# How to set webview as default viewer when opening an URL inside my app in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a class to show webview:

like this:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);

        webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview2);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

And I have another class I put data in listview. Each item is clickable in listview. when I click on item; an URL open with Tab2 class.

I done it this way:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = bookmarks.get(arg2).getURL();
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(url );
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUri);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

});
```

It works.

I run it inside my application But I have a problem.
My app (the webview) is not defult!

For example when I click on an item, a windows dialog opens and ask me choice my application or default `Android` web browser.

I do not want it. I want open my app directly. How can I do it?

Comment: You're using an implicit intent. You need an explicit intent. Look up the difference between implicit and explicit on the official android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my code to open files:

```
/**     
     * Open downloaded files
     *
     * @param context
     * @param webView  to display Html files (if null, use default browser or HTML Viewer)
     * @param filePath full local path
     * @param fileType mime_type
     */
    protected static void openFile(Context context, WebView webView, String filePath, String fileType) {
        if (fileType.equals("text/html") && (webView != null)) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.setInitialScale(1);           
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
            if (!filePath.startsWith("file://")) {
                filePath = "file://" + filePath;
            }
            webView.loadUrl(filePath);
        } else { // (pdf / word / excel files) or (html files but webView not available)
            try {
                File file = new File(filePath);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, fileType); // html files: "application/x-webarchive-xml": opened by default browser; "text/html": by HTML Viewer
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this help, anyway!